# How to attach data to post url in Android?

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am getting error. The object is building successfully but it is not attaching to the url. Please help. What is wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.

try {

```
                 String checkin = edit_message.getText().toString();
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.254/nepadeals/androidweb/checkin");
                 Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + httppost);

                        List<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
                        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("merchant_id", "02"));
                        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("merchant_location_id", "03"));
                        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", "04"));
                        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("merchant_kiosk_id", "04"));
                        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subscriber_phone", checkin));
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
             //         httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
                        if (resEntity != null) {                               
                            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                            Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);
                            Toast.makeText(CheckinActivity.this,  responseStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                            // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response
                        }               
                        edit_message.setText(""); //reset the message text field
                  //      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(CheckinActivity.this, "Data: " +data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (Throwable t) {
                     Toast.makeText(CheckinActivity.this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define content type. you can't put data with out setting its type.

so replace

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
```

with

```
httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data , "UTF-8"));
```

I hope this will work. not tested b'z i don't have function and all setup.

Comment: Much thanks! I replaced that. The problem was in the php code.